# How to replace values in another file based on user input using dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, replace

I want to take input from user for orgname, username, password and replace values in below mentioned Sample.py file.  Sample file:

```
try:
   functions.set_values(orgname='Sample', username='Sample1', password='xyz')
except:
   bail('test failed')
```

Here is what I have written :

```
while True:
    try:
        org_data = {}
        orgname = str(input('Enter orgname: '))
        username = str(input('Enter username: '))
        password = str(input('Enter password: '))

        org_data[orgname] = orgname
        org_data[username] = username
        org_data[password] = password

        break

    except ValueError:
        print('Invalid Input. Try again.')

src_file = open('Sample.py', "rt")
dest_file = open(f'Sample_{orgname}.py', "wt")
for line in src_file:
    for key,value in org_data:
        dest_file.write(line.replace(key, value))
src_file.close()
dest_file.close()
```

I get the below error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./replace_org.py", line 44, in <module>
    for key,value in org_data:
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

Comment: Looks like you are using the user input as both the key and value on the dictionary? Is that intentional?

Comment: The `ValueError` you got is _very_ likely not the only problem with your code. See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) You need to specify not only what you're trying to do, but also what results and/or errors you are getting with what you have. It's highly recommend to also provide a runnable [mre] and sample input data.

Comment: I need to take input from user for values ONLY for keys and then create a dictionary for those inputs for keys to be pre-defined. Based on dictionary defined, I need to replace values in Sample.py

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand, please add an example of the input file and the resulting output. Also, as @ENDEESA mentioned, your dictionary data makes no sense, because all values in it are the same as their corresponding keys. i.e. `{'psf': 'psf', 'guido': 'guido', 'password': 'password'}` whereas something like `{'orgname': 'psf', 'username': 'guido', 'password': 'newpw'}` would make more sense.

Answer (score 0):

part of the reason could be, you are unpacking a dictionary so you need to access the .items()

```
src_file = open('Sample.py', "rt")
dest_file = open(f'Sample_{orgname}.py', "wt")
for line in src_file:
    for key,value in org_data.Items(): #<---- unpack the values like this
        dest_file.write(line.replace(key, value))
src_file.close()
dest_file.close()
```

Comment: Thank you for replying. I added : `for key,value in org_data.items():` , but no luck. I am not sure if I am creating org_data[] dict correctly or not, since I am taking input for values only.

Comment: @Shivam: As I commented earlier, there are other problems with your code besides the `ValueError` — which have been duplicated here. Clue: Each line may be written zero or multiple times (each time differently) instead of only once.